# Neo4J - How to recover a backup (or dump) from a previous version (3.0.3) to the actual 4.1.3 Community

Tags: neo4j

How can we recover a dump from a database version 3.0.3 to the actual version 4.1.3 Community?

I've searched and tried many different alternatives, but no one have still worked.
In one of this alternatives we've tried the command
`neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=/home/ec2-user --verbose`,
but the commands to recover are not working, for example:
`neo4j-admin restore --from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/neo4j --database=system --force`
We are getting the error message:
**WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Unmatched arguments from index 0: 'restore', '--from=/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/neo4j', '--verbose', '--database=neo4j', '--force'
Did you mean: store-info or report or memrec?**

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable (but time-consuming) approach:

1. If you do not have neo4j 3.0.3 installed, get it from [here](http://www.neo4j.com/customer/download/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.3-unix.tar.gz) (as documented [here](http://www.neo4j.com/customer/download/neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4-unix.tar.gz)), and install it.
2. Follow the simple [3.0 instructions](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/backup/restore-backup/) for restoring a backup (to your 3.0.3 installation). The 3.0 restoration process is very different from the 4.x process.
3. Upgrade the 3.0.3 installation to 4.1.3, *stepwise*, by:

   - [upgrading to 3.3](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/#upgrade-instructions-3x), *then*
   - [upgrading to 3.5.22](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/upgrade/planning/#upgrade-planning), *then*
   - [migrating to 4.x](https://neo4j.com/docs/migration-guide/current/)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The community edition of neo4j doesn't have the `restore` command, only the enterprise edition does. You can take a look at the table [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/planning/#backup-planning).

[image: Revelant part of the table.]